# ARRAYS datos combinados php

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Tengo un archivo php/21print.php el cual contiene consulta y devuelve valores en ARRAY, también contiene consulta y devuelve valores en ARRAY, el archivo entrega datos en JSON como datos combinados, pero al presentarlos mediante ajax en una datatable dice que no hay datos que mostrar.

```js
<?php

session_start();
include_once '../access/dbconnect.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
  header('Location: ../index.php');
}

require_once('../access/routeros_api.class.php');
require('../access/ip.php');

?>

<?php

// Realiza la conexi�n a la base de datos
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "s@telite", "gestion_isp");

// Verifica la conexi�n
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("Error de conexion: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

// Consulta MySQL
$sql = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(FECHA, CURDATE()) AS dias_restantes FROM clientes WHERE Instalado != 'NO'";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
$datos_mysql = array();
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos_mysql[] = $fila;
}
$conexion->close();

// Consulta RouterOS
$API = new RouterosAPI();
$API->debug = false;
if ($API->connect($ServerList, $Username, $Pass, $Port)) {
    $API->write('/queue/simple/getall');
    $READ = $API->read(false);
    $ARRAY = $API->parseResponse($READ);
    $API->disconnect();

    $datos_routeros = array();
    $count = count($ARRAY);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $ip = explode('/', $ARRAY[$i]['target']);
        $speed = explode('/', $ARRAY[$i]['max-limit']);
        $datos_routeros[] = array(
            'id' => $ARRAY[$i]['.id'],
            'ip' => $ip[0],
            'name' => $ARRAY[$i]['name'],
            'up' => $speed[0] / 1000000,
            'down' => $speed[1] / 1000000,
            'comentario' => $ARRAY[$i]['comment']
        );
    }
} else {
    $datos_routeros = array();
}

// Combinar los datos de MySQL y RouterOS
$datos_combinados = array(
    'mysql' => $datos_mysql,
    'routeros' => $datos_routeros
);

// Devolver los datos en formato JSON
echo json_encode($datos_combinados);
?>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'access/dbconnect.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.1/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/floating.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .table-danger {
      background-color: #f8d7da !important;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
  th {
    font-size: 20px; /* Ajusta el tamaño del texto del encabezado según tu preferencia */
    padding-top: 0px; /* Ajusta el espacio superior del encabezado según tu preferencia */
    padding-bottom: 0px; /* Ajusta el espacio inferior del encabezado según tu preferencia */
  }
  td {
    font-size: 18px; /* Ajusta el tamaño del texto del contenido según tu preferencia */
    padding-top: 0px; /* Ajusta el espacio superior del contenido según tu preferencia */
    padding-bottom: 0px; /* Ajusta el espacio inferior del contenido según tu preferencia */
  }
</style>



</head>
<body>
    <?php require 'partial/nav-part.php' ?>

    <button id="fullscreen-btn" class="floating-button">
      <i class="fas fa-expand"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">


    <table id="tabla-pagos" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Unidad/Lugar</th>
                <th>D/Corte</th>
                <th>Canal</th>
                <th>IP</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal de Activacion -->
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Tijuana');
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');

?>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalEditarLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalEditarLabel">Editar Información <?php echo $hoy; ?></h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="pagoForm" method="post" action="php/14procesaract.php">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2 form-group">
                <label for="clienteId" class="form-label">Cliente ID:</label>
                <input id="clienteId" class="form-control" name="clienteId" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                <label for="unidad" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Unidad/Lugar</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unidad" name="unidad" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                <label for="idmkk" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Id MKK</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idmkk" name="idmkk" readonly>
              </div>
            <div class="col-6 mb-2">
              <label for="ip" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">IP</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip" name="ip" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                <label for="estado" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Estado</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                <label for="fechabd" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Fecha Sistema</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechabd" name="fechabd" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5 mb-3">
                <label for="fechaCorte" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Fecha de Corte</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaCorte" name="fechaCorte">
              </div>
              <div class="col mb-3">
                <label for="caducidad" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Caducidad</label>
                <select class="form-control" required="" id="caducidad" name="caducidad">
                  <option value="" selected="">Escoja el tiempo</option>
                  <option value="8">Semana</option>
                  <option value="30">Mes</option>
                  <option value="60">2 Meses</option>
                  <option value="91">3 Meses</option>
                  <option value="122">4 Meses</option>
                  <option value="183">6 Meses</option>
                  <option value="275">9 Meses</option>
                  <option value="365">12 Meses</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
              </div>
              </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
              <label for="cantidad" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Cantidad</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="col mb-3">
              <label for="metodoPago" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Método de Pago</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="metodoPago" name="metodoPago">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="descripcion" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Descripción</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="observacion" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Observación</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="observacion" name="observacion" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="form-check form-switch h3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" name="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Cargar en MK?</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="confirmSubmit()">Registrar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Modal de Activacion -->

<!-- Modal de Suspender -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalSus" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalSusLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalSusLabel">Editar Información <?php echo $hoy; ?></h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="pagoForm" method="post" action="php/14pr.php">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2 form-group">
                <label for="clienteId" class="form-label">Cliente ID:</label>
                <input id="clienteId" class="form-control" name="clienteId" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                <label for="unidad" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Unidad/Lugar</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unidad" name="unidad" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                <label for="idmkk" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Id MKK</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idmkk" name="idmkk" readonly>
              </div>
            <div class="col-6 mb-2">
              <label for="ip" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">IP</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip" name="ip" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                <label for="estado" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Estado</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                <label for="fechabd" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Fecha Sistema</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechabd" name="fechabd" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

              </div>
              <hr>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="descripcion" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Descripción</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="observacion" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Observación</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="observacion" name="observacion" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="form-check form-switch h3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" name="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Cargar en MK?</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="confirmSubmit()">Registrar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal de Suspender -->
  <!-- Modal de Suspender -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalinfo" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalinfoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalinfoLabel">Editar Información <?php echo $hoy; ?></h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="pagoForm" method="post" action="php/16infoprocess.php">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 mb-2 form-group">
                  <label for="clienteId" class="form-label">Cliente ID:</label>
                  <input id="clienteIdinfo" class="form-control" name="clienteIdinfo" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <label for="unidad" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Unidad/Lugar</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unidadinfo" name="unidadinfo" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <!-- Modal de Suspender
                <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                  <label for="idmkk" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Id MKK</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idmkk" name="idmkk" readonly>
                </div>-->
              <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                <label for="ip" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefonoinfo" name="telefonoinfo" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 mb-2">
                  <label for="estado" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Estado</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estadoinfo" name="estadoinfo" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <label for="fechabd" class="form-label" style="font-weight:bold;">Fecha Sistema</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechabdinfo" name="fechabdinfo" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>

                </div>
                <hr>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" >Registrar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal de Suspender -->
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"> </script>
<script nomodule   src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"> </script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.1/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/floating.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          //console.log("Document ready function executed."); // Mensaje de depuración
            // Resto del código...

            $.ajax({
                url: "php/21print.php",
                method: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    // Crea la tabla DataTable con los datos obtenidos
                    $('#tabla-pagos').DataTable({
                        data: JSON.parse(data),
                        "fixedHeader": {
                        "header": true,
                        "footer": true
                    },
                      "dom": "Blfrtip",
                        "responsive": true,
                        "select": true,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'cliente_id' },
                            { data: 'unidad_lugar' },
                            { data: 'CANAl' },
                            { data: 'IP' },

                            { data: 'observacion' }
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error al obtener los pagos de los clientes.");
                }
            });

  // Función para recargar la tabla
 function recargarTabla() {
   tabla.ajax.reload(); // Recargar la tabla mediante AJAX
 }
 function recargarPagina() {
   location.reload(); // Recargar la página
 }
  // Manejador de eventos para el botón de edición
  $('#tabla-pagos').on('click', '.btn-edit', function() {
   var clienteId = $(this).data('cliente-id');



   // Realizar la solicitud AJAX con el clienteId
   $.ajax({
     url: 'php/get_cliente.php',
     method: 'POST',
     data: { clienteId: clienteId },
     success: function(data) {
       var cliente = JSON.parse(data);

       // Mostrar los datos en los campos correspondientes
       $('#modalEditar').find('#clienteId').val(clienteId);
       $('#modalEditar').find('#unidad').val(cliente.unidad_lugar);
       $('#modalEditar').find('#estado').val(cliente.ESTADO);
       $('#modalEditar').find('#fechabd').val(cliente.FECHA);
       $('#modalEditar').find('#idmkk').val(cliente.MKK);
       $('#modalEditar').find('#ip').val(cliente.IP);




       $('#modalEditar').modal('show');
       // Completa los demás campos según tu necesidad
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
   });

   // Evento al cerrar el modal
 $('#modalEditar').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
   recargarPagina(); // Llamar a la función de recargarTabla al cerrar el modal
 });
 });
 // Manejador de eventos para el botón de Suspender
 $('#tabla-pagos').on('click', '.btn-sus', function() {
  var clienteId = $(this).data('cliente-id');



  // Realizar la solicitud AJAX con el clienteId
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/get_cliente.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { clienteId: clienteId },
    success: function(data) {
      var cliente = JSON.parse(data);

      // Mostrar los datos en los campos correspondientes
      $('#modalSus').find('#clienteId').val(clienteId);
      $('#modalSus').find('#unidad').val(cliente.unidad_lugar);
      $('#modalSus').find('#estado').val(cliente.ESTADO);
      $('#modalSus').find('#fechabd').val(cliente.FECHA);
      $('#modalSus').find('#idmkk').val(cliente.MKK);
      $('#modalSus').find('#ip').val(cliente.IP);




      $('#modalSus').modal('show');
      // Completa los demás campos según tu necesidad
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });

  // Evento al cerrar el modal
$('#modalSus').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  recargarPagina(); // Llamar a la función de recargarTabla al cerrar el modal
});
});
// Manejador de eventos para el botón de Info
$('#tabla-pagos').on('click', '.btn-info', function() {
 var clienteId = $(this).data('cliente-id');



 // Realizar la solicitud AJAX con el clienteId
 $.ajax({
   url: 'php/get_cliente.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: { clienteId: clienteId },
   success: function(data) {
     var cliente = JSON.parse(data);

     // Mostrar los datos en los campos correspondientes
     $('#modalinfo').find('#clienteIdinfo').val(clienteId);
     $('#modalinfo').find('#unidadinfo').val(cliente.unidad_lugar);
     $('#modalinfo').find('#estadoinfo').val(cliente.ESTADO);
     $('#modalinfo').find('#fechabdinfo').val(cliente.FECHA);
     //$('#modalSus').find('#idmkk').val(cliente.MKK);
     $('#modalinfo').find('#telefonoinfo').val(cliente.telefono);




     $('#modalinfo').modal('show');
     // Completa los demás campos según tu necesidad
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
 });

 // Evento al cerrar el modal
$('#modalinfo').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
 recargarPagina(); // Llamar a la función de recargarTabla al cerrar el modal
});
});




    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function confirmSubmit() {
      // Obtener el valor del checkbox
      var checkboxValue = document.getElementById("flexSwitchCheckDefault").checked;

      // Mostrar una alerta de confirmación antes de enviar el formulario
      var confirmationMessage = checkboxValue ? "¿Estás seguro de cargar en MK?" : "¿Estás seguro de continuar sin cargar en MK?";
      if (confirm(confirmationMessage)) {
        document.getElementById("pagoForm").submit(); // Enviar el formulario si se confirma
      }
    }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Los datos no se presentan la datatable, trate cargar los datos en las columnas como "mysql.cliente_id", "mysql.unidad_lugar", "routeros.id", la idea es presentar unas columnas con los datos de mysql y otro con datos obtenidos de la consulta en mikrotik pero no las carga ya revisé el archivo 21print.php y si da los datos JSON. Adjunto imagen de como los carga.una

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola alexis, intenta hacerlo así: `data: JSON.parse(data).mysql` o `data: data.mysql`. PD: En el archivo `21print.php` tenes un tag de cerrado `?>`, un salto de linea y un tag de apertura `<?php`, esto te puede traer problemas, te recomiendo borrarlos. Saludos!